# How to select a given set of indexes from an NDArray in ND4j similarly to numpy's arraydata[arrayIndex]?

Tags: java, arrays, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I am developing a scientific application relying heavily on array manipulation in Java using ND4j (presently version 1.0.0-beta5). Throughout my pipeline, I have the need to dynamically select a non contiguous subset of a [2,195102] matrix (a few tens/hundreds of columns to be more precise). 
Any idea how to achieve this in this framework?

In short, I am trying to achieve this python/numpy operation:

```py
import numpy as np
arrayData = np.array([[1, 5, 0, 6, 2, 0, 9, 0, 5, 2],
       [3, 6, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 4, 8, 1]])
arrayIndex = np.array((1,5,6))
res  = arrayData[:, arrayIndex]
# res value is
# array([[5, 0, 9],
#        [6, 3, 1]])
```

So far, I managed to select the desired column using the [NDArray.getColumns](https://javadoc.io/static/org.nd4j/nd4j-api/1.0.0-beta5/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#getColumns-int...-) function (along with the NDArray.data().asInt() from the indexArray to provide the values of the index). The problem is that the documentation explicitelly states, regarding the retrieval of information during a computation, "Note that THIS SHOULD NOT BE USED FOR SPEED" (see the documentation of [NDArray.ToIntMatrix()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.nd4j/nd4j-api/1.0.0-beta5/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#toIntMatrix--) to see the full message - different method, same operation).

I had a look at the different prototypes for [NDArray.get()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.nd4j/nd4j-api/1.0.0-beta5/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#get-org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray-) and none seem to fit the bill. I suppose that [NDArray.getWhere()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.nd4j/nd4j-api/1.0.0-beta5/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.html#getWhere-org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray-org.nd4j.linalg.indexing.conditions.Condition-) might work - if it, as I assume, only returns the elements that fulfil the condition - but have been, so far, unsuccessful in making use of it. The documentation is relatively light when it comes to explain the arguments/usage required.

Thank you all for your time and help :)

EDIT (04/11/2019):
Some precision regarding what I have tried. I played around with NDArray.get() and made use of the indexes:

```java
INDArray arrayData = Nd4j.create(new int[]
                    {1, 5, 0, 6, 2, 0, 9, 0, 5, 2,
                     3, 6, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 4, 8, 1},   new long[]{2, 10}, DataType.INT);
INDArray arrayIndex = Nd4j.create(new int[]{1, 5, 6}, new long[]{1,  3}, DataType.INT);

INDArray colSelection = null;

//index free version
colSelection = arrayData.getColumns(arrayIndex.toIntVector());
/*
* colSelection value is
* [[5, 0, 9],
*  [6, 3, 1]]
* but the toIntVector() call pulls the data from the back-end storage
* and re-inject them. That is presumed to be slow.
*  -   2 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5}),        ==> 4001 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   3 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6}),     ==> 5339 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   4 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6 ,2}),  ==> 7016 ms for 100000 iterations
*/

//index version
colSelection = arrayData.get(NDArrayIndex.all(), NDArrayIndex.indices(arrayIndex.toLongVector()));
/*
* Same result, but same problem regarding toLongVector() this time around.
*  -   2 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5}),        ==> 3200 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   3 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6}),     ==> 4269 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   4 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6 ,2}),  ==> 5252 ms for 100000 iterations
*/

//weird but functional version (that I just discovered)
colSelection = arrayData.transpose().get(arrayIndex); // the transpose operation is necessary to not hit an IllegalArgumentException: Illegal slice 5
// note that transposing the arrayIndex leads to an IllegalArgumentException: Illegal slice 6 (as it is trying to select the element at the line idx 1, column 5, depth 6, which does not exist)
/*
* colSelection value is
* [5, 6, 0, 3, 9, 1]
* The array is flattened... calling a reshape(arrayData.shape()[0],arrayIndex.shape()[1]) yields
* [[5, 6, 0],
*  [3, 9, 1]]
* which is wrong.
*/
colSelection = colSelection.reshape(arrayIndex.shape()[1],arrayData.shape()[0]).transpose();
/* yields the right result
* [[5, 0, 9],
*  [6, 3, 1]]
* While this seems to be the correct way to handle the memory the performance are low:
*  -   2 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5}),        ==> 8225 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   3 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6}),     ==> 8980 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   4 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6 ,2}),  ==> 9453 ms for 100000 iterations
Plus, this is very roundabout method for such a "simple" operation
* if the repacking of the data is commented out, the timing become:
*  -   2 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5}),        ==> 6987 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   3 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6}),     ==> 7976 ms for 100000 iterations
*  -   4 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6 ,2}),  ==> 8336 ms for 100000 iterations
*/
```

Those speed my seem alright without knowing what machine I am running, but the equivalent python code yields:

- 2 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5}),          ==> 171 ms for 100000 iterations
- 3 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6}),       ==> 173 ms for 100000 iterations
- 4 columns selected (arrayIndex = {1, 5, 6 ,2}),    ==> 173 ms for 100000 iterations

Those java implementations re at best 20 times slower than the python-numpy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray arr = org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.create(new double[][]{
                {1, 5, 0, 6, 2, 0, 9, 0, 5, 2},
                {3, 6, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 4, 8, 1}
        });

        org.nd4j.linalg.indexing.INDArrayIndex indices[] = {
                org.nd4j.linalg.indexing.NDArrayIndex.all(),
                new org.nd4j.linalg.indexing.SpecifiedIndex(1,5,6)
        };

        org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray selected = arr.get(indices);
        System.out.println(selected);
    }
```

This should work for you. This prints:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

```
[[    5.0000,         0,    9.0000], 
 [    6.0000,    3.0000,    1.0000]]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your answer. I have added some precision as an edit to my question. Indeed, I have *functional* implementations. But none that is actually efficient.

Comment: Try my edited response?This reproduces what you're doing in numpy.

Comment: Hi Adam, I took the time to try this out during the week end. It indeed works, with performance similar to the solution I tried using NDArrayIndex.indices(arrayIndex.toLongVector()). The bottle neck being the acquisition of the data from the arrayIndex (and, therefore, the memory transfer from un-managed to managed memory). I'll nonetheless accept it as the correct answer since it answers the question title. Thank you :)

Comment: Right you can't really avoid that though. This requires a copy. There's no way to really do that with a view. Numpy has similar edge cases.